# What did Christians write about Muhammad during his life?

Tags: history, islam

Are there any records written by Christians about Muhammad that were written during his life? If so, what did they say about him? I would be very surprised if the Church of ~600-630 AD didn't have *something* to say about a man claiming to be the prophet of God.

Comment: That depends. It took a long while for Muhammad's followers to go from being a small tribal group (of which there were plenty) to something​ big enough to get the attention of the state religion of the Roman Empire.

Answer (score 4):

The most notable early Christian writing that I am aware of was by John of Damascus (676-749).  In *Heresies in Epitome: How They Began and Whence They Drew Their Origin* he claims that the basis of Mohammed's fundamental teachings came from an Arian monk:

> There is also the superstition of the Ishmaelites which to this day
>   prevails and keeps people in error, being a forerunner of the
>   Antichrist. They are descended from Ishmael, [who] was born to Abraham
>   of Agar, and for this reason they are called both Agarenes and
>   Ishmaelites. They are also called Saracens, which is derived from
>   Sarras kenoi, or destitute of Sara, because of what Agar said to the
>   angel: ‘Sara hath sent me away destitute.’  These used to be idolaters
>   and worshiped the morning star and Aphrodite, whom in their own
>   language they called Khabár, which means great.  And so down to the
>   time of Heraclius they were very great idolaters. From that time to
>   the present a false prophet named Mohammed has appeared in their
>   midst. This man, after having chanced upon the Old and New Testaments
>   and likewise, it seems, having conversed with an Arian monk,  devised
>   his own heresy. Then, having insinuated himself into the good graces
>   of the people by a show of seeming piety, he gave out that a certain
>   book had been sent down to him from heaven. He had set down some
>   ridiculous compositions in this book of his and he gave it to them as
>   an object of veneration.

The rest of the text can be found [here](http://orthodoxinfo.com/general/stjohn_islam.aspx).

Some say that the iconoclast heresy in Byzantium arose because certain Christians were envious of the material success of surrounding Moslems and surmised that their practices - especially their rejection of depictions of human form - were earning them God's favor.  John of Damascus was one of the most vocal critics of the iconoclast Emperor Leo the Isaurian.  Ironically, John wrote his *Apologetic Treatises against those Decrying the Holy Images* while under the protection of a nearby moslem caliph.